# Stripping &nbsp; out of RSS feed with PHP

Tags: php, xml, encoding, rss

I have this function:

```
function validate($data) {
    $newData = str_replace("&nbsp;", " ", $newData);
    $newData = utf8_encode(htmlentities(strip_tags($data)));
    return $newData;
}

$rssfeed.='<description><![CDATA['.validate($news).']]></description>';
```

MY MySQL table that it draws from uses utf8-general_ci encoding.

However, my XML feed still has `&nbsp;` in it.  Any ideas why?

Comment: it actually shows &nbsp in the feed preview in Chrome; but shows it with the &amp in the actual feed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using your variables in the wrong order, so you are ignoring the result of `str_replace`.

```
$newData = str_replace("&nbsp;", " ", $newData);
$newData = utf8_encode(htmlentities(strip_tags($data)));
```

should be

```
$newData = str_replace("&nbsp;", " ", $data);
$newData = utf8_encode(htmlentities(strip_tags($newData)));
```

Comment: thanks I am marking this the right answer because that removed it from the feed.  Its odd that the Google Reader client still shows the &nbsp but that may just be a browser issue, not sure.

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't your function look like:

```
function validate($data) { 
    $newData = str_replace("&nbsp;", " ", $data); 
    $newData = utf8_encode(htmlentities(strip_tags($newData))); 
    return $newData; 
}
```